# Что не так с моим Json массивом android?

Tags: android, массивы, json

Я на сервер хочу отправить массив состоящий из файлов, для этого я конвертирую файлы в base64 и отправляю в массив. Вот как массив должен выглядеть:

```
"attach": [
{"filename": "preved.doc",  "data": BASE64_FILE_ENCODED},
...
]
```

а вот как я его формирую:

```
{"attach":{"values":[]}
```

по какой-то непонятной причине у меня создается массив values который вообще мне не нужен. Вот как я отправляю файлы в массив:

```
ms.setArray(uploadFiles(new FileUpload(selected.getName(), readBytesFromFile(selected.getPath()))));
```

и вот метод:

```
public JSONArray uploadFiles(FileUpload fileUpload) {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("attach", fileUpload);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return array;
    }
```

все вроде работает так как нужно, ну то есть в base64 вроде все конвертируется правильно, но дальше какая-то непонятная магия происходит. Может я массив не так формирую, потому что я не очень понял разницу между **JSONArray** и **JsonArray** может я не то что нужно использую. Надеюсь на вашу помощь в решении этой ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась довольно просто и я был если честно удивлен. У меня использовался такой массив **JSONArray**  а нужно было **JsonArray** . После того как я везде провел замену, все стало нормально работать, кроме добавления в массив файла :) Надеюсь эта информация будет кому-то полезна.